# I can not see the jquery ui icon but the text inside the span was displayed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can not see the jquery ui icon but the text inside the span was displayed. Anyway to troubleshoot this. When I used firebug, I don't see the css code when highlighting the span tag.

```
 <TITLE> Test </TITLE>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=""file:///C:/test/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css">
 <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></SCRIPT>
 <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="jquery.layout-latest.js"></SCRIPT>
 <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></SCRIPT>


 <div id="top" class="north"> 
 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-w" style="float:left;">This is a test</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two double quotes after the `href=` in your `<link>` tag.

Comment: I can not believe I overlooked that. Super thanks for Daniel for xray eyes. Its now working...